# Do the players in Poker Night at the inventory have built in "tells"?

Tags: poker-night-at-the-inventory

I'm just wondering if the players in this game exhibit "tells" that I should be paying attention to in order to have a strategic advantage when I play, or if it is relatively random.

Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I've seen Tycho and Max exhibit a tell.  Only once for each of them, when they had something like pocket aces and flopped another ace.  There is specific reference [in the update news](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4737/) about the characters showing a tell.  Tells, as far as I can tell, are a random occurrence when the character has a good hand.

Comment: What tell did they show?

Comment: It was very obvious. Max jumped up on his seat and Tycho eyes widened.

Answer (score 2):

Not from my experience (I tried to watch for tells too and it didn't work out for me), but its rather easy to figure out their personalities very early on.  The AI is not that good, even on hard mode.  As long as your hand is fairly solid you have a very easy way of exploiting the AI.

For example, a very small raise (of the default amount) at the start of every betting round will get the AI to call it almost guaranteed.

As for personalities, the heavy tends to be very aggressive, i.e. make randomly large raises with nothing after the flop.  If your hand is even half decent, you can do a bigger raise and he'll fold.  On the rare chance his cards are good, he'll probably reraise and then you know to drop the hand.

Max, as near as I can tell, is psychotic and random a lot more than others.  Tycho is very low risk most of the time and will rarely call your high bid unless his hands are good.  Strongbad is somewhere in between those two.

Also, if the AI ever raises on multiple rounds or twice in a round, then its almost guaranteed his hand is at least decent.

Answer (score -1):

http://theinventory.wikia.com/wiki/Tells
this has all the known tells on it

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. What happens if the page linked to moves or is deleted?

Comment: Yep, this is good info, but it would be good to copy the content here (while leaving the source link) so that it can't get lost.